# Having some trouble with Matrix rotations in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

What I have so far:
I start out with a triangle mesh to get the polygon centers and normals to place more triangle meshes around the first one. I then use those new ones to place even more. So far that part works out.
[image: triangle placement]

I can even adjust the rotation on the last iteration of triangles to fold them together.
[image: rotate triangles]

But here comes the part I have trouble with. The moment I adjust the rotation on the FIRST iteration of triangles the SECOND iteration does not behave as I want to. I know that I have to adjust the matrices somehow, but for the life of me, I can't figure this out.
[image: messed up matrices]

Here is the node tree hopefully a bit bigger and better to read:
[image: nodetree animation nodes]

Every bit of help is very much appreciated.
Thank you :)